# What determines rank in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

How does Mario Kart Wii decide your rank letter (A, B, C, D, E, F) or star in a Cup that you raced?

Comment: Marking an answer as accepted no longer awards a bounty. Could you award it before it expires?

Comment: @Macha - Done, thanks. I thought it still happened automatically when you accepted the answer (which makes more sense to me).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no official information on what determines your rank. A good track time seems to matter the most, but many elements are speculated to also help:

Positively:

- lowest possible race finish time
- amount of time spent in 1st place
- boosts from mini-turbo, beginning of race, tricks
- successful item attacks
- successful wheelies

Negatively:

- falling off track or being slowed down by offroad areas
- hitting walls or obstacles

Though these are not confirmed, they serve as good guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that no one knows.  Some sites on the Internet claim that it is based on how often you went off the track, but I think it is more likely based on simple time around the course.  Since going off course slows you down, it would be easy to confuse the two.

My belief (completely unconfirmed) with regards to the one, two and three star rankings is that if you beat the required time, you get the stars based on how many laps you were the fastest kart on the track.  So for the three star ranking, you would need to be the fastest kart the entire race.  However, it is difficult to get any data to back my belief up, so I'm probably wrong...

Comment: When you say fastest cart for the entire race do you mean never being overtaken or just finishing each lap 1st?

Comment: Fastest lap each of the three laps, so finishing each lap 1st.  I've never received a three star ranking unless I have been in 1st at the end of every lap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 90% sure that it it the time you got in the race (e.g. getting under x minutes gets a C) although the time required for the rank is different on each course.